# How to execute text from stdout in bash

Tags: linux, bash

So I have a command that's like

`cmd1|cmd2|...|cmdN|execute`

The output of `cmdN` is one line that I want `execute` to execute as if I copy pasted the output of `cmdN` into the terminal myself. I've tried to replace `execute` with `bash`, with `$`, and I tried to use `xargs`. (I'm still kinda confused on each of the options I've tried).

What's the simple answer here that's gonna make me wanna delete this post?

Comment: `eval`. [But don't.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute it in the current shell, use the `eval` command:

```
eval "$(cmd1|cmd2|...|cmdN)"
```

If it can be executed in a subshell, pipe to `bash`:

```
cmd1|cmd2|...|cmdN | bash
```